# How to determine the eigenvalues and the multiplicity of the eigenvalues of this symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algorithms

Suppose we are given a family of $k$ vectors $(\vec{v}_1,\dots,\vec{v}_k)$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $\vec{v}_i\cdot\vec{v}_i=1$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$ and $||\vec{v}_i-\vec{v}_j||=1$ for all $i\neq j$. How do we compute the eigen values and their multiplicity of the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)

$$GM(\vec{v}_1,\dots,\vec{v}_k)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_1 & \vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_2 &\dots &\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_k\\
\vec{v}_2\cdot\vec{v}_1 & \vec{v}_2\cdot\vec{v}_2 & \dots &\vec{v}_2\cdot\vec{v}_k\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
\vec{v}_k\cdot\vec{v}_1 & \vec{v}_k\cdot\vec{v}_2&\dots&\vec{v}_k\cdot\vec{v}_k
\end{pmatrix} $$

I understand that, by hypothesis, we have $\vec{v}_i\cdot\vec{v}_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$ which in turn implies
$$\begin{align*}
||\vec{v}_i-\vec{v}_j||^2
=\vec{v}_i\cdot\vec{v}_i - 2(\vec{v}_i\cdot\vec{v}_j)+\vec{v}_j\cdot\vec{v}_j
=2-2(\vec{v}_i\cdot\vec{v}_j)
\end{align*} $$

so that $$\vec{v}_i\cdot\vec{v}_j=\frac{1}{2}$$ for all $i\neq j$.

This means $$GM(\vec{v}_1,\dots,\vec{v}_k)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2} &\dots & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \dots &\frac{1}{2}\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}&\dots&1
\end{pmatrix} $$

but I am unsure how to continue from here. More generally, is there a method to computing the eigenvales/characteristic polynomials of large symmetric matrices?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. (For context, [see this paper](https://rak.ac/publication/2011-explorations-on-the-dimension-of-a-graph/graph.pdf) on page four).

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899154/characteristic-polynomial-of-a-square-matrix-of-size-n-with-all-entries-equal : if the all 1s matrix is $J$ then your matrix is $\frac{1}{2}(J+I)$

Comment: @ancientmathematician my linear algebra skills aren't too polished yet. do you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: The ev of $J$ are $n$ once and $0$ $n-1$ times. So the ev of $I+J$ are $n+1$ once and $1$ $n-1$ times. So the ev of your matrix are half these. This is standard in adjacency theory of graphs.

Comment: @ancientmathematician ok, thank you. i didn't realize that ev's behaved that way with matrix addition

Comment: Caution: adding the identity matrix is safe, but it's not true for $A+B$ in general.

Comment: @ancientmathematician right. was just thinking about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have an $n\times n$ matrix of the form
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b &\cdots & b\\
b & a & \cdots &b\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
b & b&\cdots&a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some non-zero $b$, you can use two observations to determine the eigenvalues and their multiplicities:

1. The matrix $A-(a-b)I$ has all entries equal to $b$, hence is of rank $1$. This means that $a-b$ is an eigenvalue of geometric multiplicity $n-1$.
2. All row sums are equal to $a+(n-1)b$, so that the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)^{\textrm t}$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $a+(n-1)b$. The geometric multiplicity has to be $1$ since the other eigenspace is already of dimension $n-1$ and distinct eigenspaces always form direct sums.