# Factorizing a polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, factoring, characteristic-polynomial

> Factorize the polynomial
>
> $$P(x)= \begin{vmatrix}
> a_1^2-x & a_{1}a_2 & a_1a_3 & \cdots  & a_1a_n \\
> a_2a_1 & a_2^2-x & a_{2}a_3 & \cdots & a_2a_n\\
> a_3a_1 & a_3a_2 & a_3^2-x & \cdots & a_3a_n \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> a_na_1 & a_na_2 & a_na_3 & \cdots & a_n^2-x\\
> \end{vmatrix}$$

I was thinking of getting the eigenvalues for the matrix , however i couldn't find a way to determine them.

I also tried to get the determinant for n=2 :

determinant = $X(X-(a_1^2+a_2^2))$

However that alone is not sufficient to generalize the determinant

Any hints or advices appreciated.

I would also be grateful if anyone would know somewhere where i can tackle similar problems .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it help that the matrix could be symmetric?

Comment: @DietrichBurde my bad ,was a typo

Comment: For $n=3$, we [get](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det%5B%5Ba%5E2-x,a+b,+a+c%5D,%5Bb+a,+b%5E2-x,+b+c%5D,%5Bc+a,+c+b,+c%5E2-x%5D%5D) $x^2 (a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 - x)$.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern , A symmetric matrix is always diagonalizable is all i can think of.

Comment: Let $x=a_1^2 a_2^2 \cdots a_n^2 y$ ... spot any factors ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553812/matrixs-determinant for inspiration

Comment: If you put $x=0$, then the matrix is equal to $(a_1,...,a_n)^T\cdot(a_1,...,a_n)$, which is a rank $1$ matrix. Therefore, it has an $(n-1)$-dimensional kernel. Hence the eigenspace of $0$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional. Therefore $x^{n-1}$ is a factor of the determinant. The other factor must be linear. So, you just need to prove that $a_1^2+...+a_n^2$ is a root too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The determinant is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1^2 & a_{1}a_2 & a_1a_3 & \cdots  & a_1a_n \\
a_2a_1 & a_2^2 & a_{2}a_3 & \cdots & a_2a_n\\
a_3a_1 & a_3a_2 & a_3^2 & \cdots & a_3a_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_na_1 & a_na_2 & a_na_3 & \cdots & a_n^2\\
\end{pmatrix}
=(a_1,...,a_n)^T\cdot(a_1,...,a_n)
$$
As mentioned in the comments, this matrix
has rank $1$ and so has a kernel of dimension $n-1$. Thus, $0$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $n-1$.

The cases $n=1,2,3$ suggest that $a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$, which is easy to verify.

Therefore, the characteristic polynomial of the matrix is $(-1)^{n}x^{n-1}(x-(a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2))$.

Comment: I think there shouldn't be an x in the 3rd column of the matrix.

Comment: And i'm not quite sure where did the $(-1)^{n-1}$ come from , is it because $-x$ is multiplied $n-1$ times when calculating the determinant?

Comment: @Raku, all fixed, thanks.